# How Find Digits in Csharp

Tags: c#

I want write program to get 10 numbers and if input number for exampel more then 3 digit write hello !

How to find out how many digits the number x is ?

Comment: You could divide by 10 until the number is 0 (integer). There is an option using logarithms but this is probably simpler for a beginner.

Comment: Taking user input will make it a string. Check if the string is a digit, and then check the length of the string.

Comment: @spirit that's possible but you'd also need to check if the number string started with + or - since that would add an extra character.

Comment: A number (assuming integer) of more than 3 digits is greater than 999

Comment: @As_t, I hope this is the answer you needed. Next time try to be more specific, it is not clear where the inserted numbers are coming from.

Comment: This is not a good question for StackOverflow. Some basic web research/training should have got you to at least part of an answer which you might need some help understanding. All you are doing here is asking for someone to do your work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I understood you right this is what I think you need:

```
//MainCode
Random rnd = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    GetNumberAmountOfDigits(rnd.Next());
}

//function to get amount of digits in an number
int GetNumberAmountOfDigits(int number)
{
    if (number == 0){
        return 1;
    }

    int count = 0;
    while (number != 0)
    {
        number /= 10;
        count++;
    }
            
    return count;
}
```

I assumed it was not a user insert, in that case, you could also just get the string length. (as stated in the conversation in the reactions)

Comment: I'd suggest `!= 0` since this will return 0 for negative numbers.

Comment: For number=0, this will return 0 instead of 1.